# how to know which list has been selected in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, itemlistener

i have two Choice List in a program, i have added ItemListener to both the lists.
How to know which list has been selected by user in itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)?

is there any method to identify the source of event in case of ItemListener as there is getSource() in ActionListener.

Comment: `ItemEvent#getSource` will return a reference to the object which generated the event.  If you have a read through the JavaDocs, you will see that both `ItemListener` and `ActionListener` extended from the same base `EventObject`, which is where `getSource` is actually defined

Answer (score 3):

In `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)` you get an `ItemEvent`.

Looking at [`ItemEvent API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html) you have `getItemSelectable()` method:

```
public ItemSelectable getItemSelectable()
```

> Returns the originator of the event.

Use it.

Comment: sorry... i'm not getting your point... can you please add an answer or clarify? Comboboxes are selectable elements right? so IMO this method will return the Combobox originating the event, isn't it? Am I misunderstanding the method?

Comment: Hmmm, this is actually a good point, less obvious then `getSource`, I took it as `getItem` - ignore my stupidity ;)

Comment: Dont worry :) It happens to me all the time. Also, you're legend here, so I wanted to be sure of my words because english is not my mother language and sometimes I'm missing obvious things. Thanks4that!!

Answer (score 3):

> How to know which list has been selected by user

`ItemEvent#getSource` will return a reference to the object which generated the event.

If you have a read through the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html), you will see that both `ItemEvent` and `ActionEvent` extended from the same base `EventObject`, which is where `getSource` is actually defined